# Row is coming at same line in Bootstrap 3

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Two rows are coming at same line in bootstrap-3..
Here is my code to chat screen of two people

Code

```
[<div class="row single-row mt-10" style="float: left !important;>
    <div class="col-2" style="margin: auto; background-color: silver; padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 0px !important;">
        <div class="profile-container">
            <img \[src\]="address"
                style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
            <div class="row">
            <span class="clr-col-12 msg_time"> 
                {{date : 'MMM d, y h:mm a' }}
            </span>     
        </div>                                
        <div class=" row mb-10 msg_cotainer">
            {{m?.messageText}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" *ngIf="file">
            <span>File name</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>][1]
```

and I want like this --
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfUwr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a problem with your html

1. you forgot to close style tag quotes in first line
   This line

should be

```
<div class="row single-row mt-10" style="float: left !important;">
```

2. and i think you forgot to add row class in file Name parent div

add a row div above this  div

Comment: no, this mistake is happened at typing . the code is correct

Comment: and what about missing row above the file div .. did you check that ?

Comment: did yo manage to sort out the problem with HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the image you have sent, you can use below code:

```
<!-- Left-aligned -->
  <div class="media">
   <div class="media-left">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="media-object rounded" style="width:60px" />
   </div>
    <div class="media-body">
         <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
         <h4 class="date"> 2021-5-22</h4>
    </div>
</div>
 <!-- Right-aligned -->
 <div class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <h4 class="date"> 2021-5-22</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="media-right">
     <img src="images/img2.jpg" class="media-object rounded" style="width:60px" />
     </div>
 </div>
```

//Css

```
 <style>
        .media-body p {
            background: yellowgreen;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: fit-content;
            padding: 0 5px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .date {
            color: #bbb;
            font-size: 11px;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .media, .media-body{
            width: fit-content;
        }
    </style>
```